# Automating Winmerge comparison in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, compare, differentiation

I require an assistant with coding a comparison between two tables in Python, that is currently done in winmerge.

The code is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
```

Last week's table

```
df1=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\ri0a\OneDrive - Department of Environment, Land, Water and Planning\Python practice\pvmodules+_210326.csv")
```

This week table with new model numbers, and expire dates

```
df2=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\ri0a\OneDrive - Department of Environment, Land, Water and Planning\Python practice\pvmodules+_210401.csv")
```

The table head is as below

[image]

the third column is PV_module certificate: Expiry date. I want to set a logic similar to excel logic '=IF (D2<DATEVALUE("19/04/2021"),"Expired","OK). The objective here is to delete the entire rows where the expiry date is below a specific date/ today's date.

Next,Importing dataframe_diff package

```
from dataframe_diff import dataframe_diff
```

Executing the difference

```
d1_column,d2_additional=dataframe_diff(df1,df2,key=['PV Module Certificate: Licensee/Certificate Holder Account','Model Number/s'])
```

With this package d2_additional shows if there are new rows associated with model numbers added this week compared to last week.
[image]

However, I am trying to replicate the following output

[image]

The tasks involved are

1. If some model, in this case a row, was included in the last week's table, but is missing in current week's table, I want to assign a new field "Expired" in a new column "Status" next to it./ Or create a new dataframe, d2_expires, from only those missing rows.
2. Another dataframe, where the rows or the product models that were missing last week but added this week remains...As d2_additional.
3. A third dataframe, where any changes (for example expiry date) for same rows (same cerificate + same model but different new expiry date) is captures as d3_comparison.

Now: as with

```
d2_expires = merged_df[merged_df._merge == 'left_only']
```

and with

```
d2_additional = merged_df[merged_df._merge == 'right_only']
```

I get the same output. Same rows are returned, which should not be the case.
As seen from the screen below

[image: Expires output]

This is the same as additions
[image: d2_aDDITIONS IS THE SAME OUTPUT AS D2_EXPIRES]

And Finally, I get an error with d2_comaprison.

```
d3_comparison = merged_df[merged_df._merge == 'both'].\
        loc[lambda x: x.PV Module Certificate: Expiry Date_last_week != x.PV Module Certificate: Expiry Date_this_week]
```

[image: error]

Comment: Thanks for fixing that. If your question is about understanding this code, then please describe what you understand of it and what specific part you don't. The question text itself right now seems very different though. It seems like you are looking for information on how to write a loop around this code? You're looking for `dir` to get a listing of files, and `for` to iterate over those files and apply this code to each?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to ensure to convert the dates into datetime format after loading the data, and rename the columns to something easier to work with (for example 'cert_holder', 'model_no','approval_date','expiry_date')

> I want to set a logic similar to excel logic '=IF
> (D2<DATEVALUE("19/04/2021"),"Expired","OK). The objective here is to
> delete the entire rows where the expiry date is below a specific date/
> today's date.

This (removing) can be done with:

```
df = df[df['expiry_date'] >= pd.Timestamp('today')]

# Or

df = df[df['expiry_date'] >= pd.Timestamp('2021-04-23')]
```

But this only works, if your expiry dates are in datetime format.

Next merge the two dataframes:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='outer', on=['cert_holder','model_no'],\
                     suffixes=['_last_week','_this_week'], indicator=True)
```

> If some model, in this case a row, was included in the last week's
> table, but is missing in current week's table, I want to assign a new
> field "Expired" in a new column "Status" next to it./ Or create a new
> dataframe, d2_expires, from only those missing rows.

```
d2_expires = merged_df[merged_df._merge == 'left_only']
```

> Another dataframe, where the rows or the product models that were
> missing last week but added this week remains...As d2_additional.

```
d2_additional = merged_df[merged_df._merge == 'right_only']
```

> A third dataframe, where any changes (for example expiry date) for
> same rows (same certificate + same model but different new expiry date)
> is captures as d3_comparison.

```
d3_comparison = merged_df[merged_df._merge == 'both'].\
        loc[lambda x: x.expiry_date_last_week != x.expiry_date_this_week]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this and will update my findings. Please advise how to declare a column as date Time?

Comment: `df['column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column'])`. If it does not recognize the d/m/y correctly, you have to extend with `df['column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column'], format='%d/%m/%Y')`

Comment: Thank you for helping. I am still facing issues. I have updated the post with the issues that arises. I can send you the files if I had an email address.